# Stored procedure in Oracle with Case and When

Tags: stored-procedures, oracle11g

I am having a scenario, where I am having 5 different tables:

```
Table 1 - Product, Columns - ProductId, BatchNummer, Status, GroupId, OrderNummer

Table 2 - ProductGrop, Columns - GropId, ProductType, Description

Table 3 - Electronics, Columns - EId, Description, BatchNummer, OrderNummer, OrderData

Table 4 - Manual, Columns - MId, Description, Status, OrderNummer, ProcessStep

Table 5 - ProcessedProduct, columns same as Product with one extra column of datetime
```

Now, according to business flow, I need to populate all the data from Product table, and have to check if the underlying table (Electronics or Manual, which depends on ProductType column of ProductGoup) has ordernuumer value, then Insert a record in table 5 "ProcessedProduct" else skip the records.

For this requirement, i want to create a procedure. But I am stuck on how to check which underlying table (Electronics/Manual) shall i have to refer and how it can be achieved.

Moreover how should i write the loop for inserting the records.

Note: I cannot change the tables schema.

Comment: First of all, can you post here - what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

With a PL/SQL procedure you can just switch within a LOOP, but you don't need an imperative algoritm if you just need to check if OrderNummer is either into Electronics or Manuals.

Supposing the detail table is chosen by ProductType value either "Electronics" or "Manuals", you could:

```
INSERT INTO ProcessedProduct (ProductId, BatchNummer, Status, GroupId, OrderNummer, TS)
SELECT ProductId, BatchNummer, Status, GroupId, OrderNummer, SYSDATE
FROM Product p 
INNER JOIN ProductGroup pg USING (GroupId)
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT NULL FROM Electronics e
  WHERE p.OrderNummer = e.OrderNummer
  AND pg.ProductType = 'Electronics'
  UNION
  SELECT NULL FROM Manuals m
  WHERE m.OrderNummer = m.OrderNummer 
  AND pg.ProductType = 'Manuals')
```

Plain SQL is always the fastest way, and "WHERE EXISTS" is usually the fastest condition.